# Tcpdump : Unable to capture packets from Python script

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to open Tcpdump to capture UDP packets from a Python script. Here is my code:

```
os.system("tcpdump -i wlp2s0 -n dst 8.8.8.8 -w decryptedpackets.pcap &")
testfile = urllib.URLopener()
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
host = "8.8.8.8"
port = 5000
buf = 1024
addr = (host, port)
s.connect((host, port))
f = open("file.txt", "rb")
data = f.read(buf)

while (data):
    if (s.sendto(data, addr)):
        print "sending ..."
        data = f.read(buf)
```

I am able to capture the packets (pcap file has content) if I manually execute this command in shell:

```
tcpdump -i wlp2s0 -n dst 8.8.8.8 -w decryptedpackets.pcap &
```

However, If I use os.system() I can't capture the packets. ( When I open the pcap file, I find it empty)

I have verified and found that there is a process that gets created when the Python script is executed:

> root     10092  0.0  0.0  17856  1772 pts/19   S    10:25   0:00
>   tcpdump -i wlp2s0 -n dst 8.8.8.8 -w decryptedpackets.pcap

Also, I'm running this as a sudo user to avoid any permission problems.

Any suggestions what could be causing this problem ?

Comment: What exactly *is* the problem? You're having `tcpdump` write packets to a `.pcap` file. And your `ps` output shows that it's been successfully launched. So that part seems to be working. But then you're opening a `file.txt` and sending its contents to a remote host. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: The problem is that if I execute the os.system() the pcap file is empty with no captured packets. However, if I manually run the tcpdump command in shell, the pcap file has content

Comment: Don't use `&` and pick a good alternative from the `subprocess` module.

Comment: I actually need to run this process in background. I want tcpdump to start listening on an interface then sending out the packets to capture them. I tried subprocess.check_output(['tcpdump', '-i', 'wlp2s0', '(dst 8.8.8.8)', '-w', 'decryptedpackets.pcap']) but not able to run it in background

Comment: @JElias: did you use the `-w` switch too when running from the command line instead of the script? If not your problem might be buffering  and you should have a look at the `-U` option. Apart from that the `-w` switch should be used *before* the capture expression, i.e. the expression should be the last thing. In summary: `tcpdump -i wlp2s0 -n -w out.pcap -U dst 8.8.8.8`

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for the advice! That solved the problem. Great job!

Answer (score 0):

From [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html).

> os.system(command) Execute the command (a string) in a subshell. This
>   is implemented by calling the Standard C function system(), and has
>   the same limitations. Changes to sys.stdin, etc. are not reflected in
>   the environment of the executed command.
>
> On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in
>   the format specified for wait(). Note that POSIX does not specify the
>   meaning of the return value of the C system() function, so the return
>   value of the Python function is system-dependent.
>
> On Windows, the return value is that returned by the system shell
>   after running command, given by the Windows environment variable
>   COMSPEC: on command.com systems (Windows 95, 98 and ME) this is always
>   0; on cmd.exe systems (Windows NT, 2000 and XP) this is the exit
>   status of the command run; on systems using a non-native shell,
>   consult your shell documentation.
>
> The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning
>   new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is
>   preferable to using this function. See the Replacing Older Functions
>   with the subprocess Module section in the subprocess documentation for
>   some helpful recipes.

I think that `os.system` returns immediately and the script keeps going, there's no problem with the code but you probably need to create a separate thread and call `os.system` with the `tcp-dump` since I believe that it is returning immediately.

Answer (score -1):

did you use the `-w` switch too when running from the command line instead of the script? If not your problem might be buffering  and you should have a look at the `-U` option. Apart from that the `-w` switch should be used *before* the capture expression, i.e. the expression should be the last thing. In summary: `tcpdump -i wlp2s0 -n -w out.pcap -U dst 8.8.8.8`
                    – Steffen Ullrich